# Find and reshape duplicated rows into one row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ['01', '02', '03', '04'], "A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"], "B":[0,1,1,1], "C":["A","A","B","A"]})

   id    A  B  C
0  01  foo  0  A
1  02  foo  1  A
2  03  foo  1  B
3  04  bar  1  A
```

I want to put all rows into one row if their values in column A value are same, how can do it with pandas? thanks.

```
   id   A   B  C   id   A   B   C   id    A   B   C
0  01  foo  0  A   02  foo  1   A   03   foo  1   B
1  04  bar  1  A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following works:

```
new_df = (df.groupby('A',as_index=False,sort=False)
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.flatten()))
          .unstack())    

new_df.columns = pd.np.tile(df.columns,len(new_df.columns)//len(df.columns))

>>> new_df
   id    A  B  C    id     A     B     C    id     A     B     C
0  01  foo  0  A    02   foo     1     A    03   foo     1     B
1  04  bar  1  A  None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
```